# Correct way of saying a decision has been made

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-requests, formality

What is the correct way of saying "decision has been made on a paper"?

I review papers submitted by officials. Is it OK to say it like this?

> This paper has already been decision by Sam Rick.

I am looking for a formal way to convey this message.

Comment: Is Sam Rick the only person involved in making a decision regarding this paper?

Comment: You might be interested in our proposed sister site for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2). You can support it by committing. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you want:

> This paper has already been reviewed by Sam Rick.

Or

> A decision on this paper has already been made by Sam Rick.

Comment: Off topic (critique request).

Comment: Better to put the subject first... "Sam Rick already reviewed this paper."

Answer (score 5):

Assuming OP's intended sense is that Sam Rick has already made the decision, it's theoretically possible to say...

> This paper has already been **decided upon** by Sam Rick.

...but in practice we don't normally use that form. I think if it's important to emphasise that a decision *was actually made* (as opposed to simply saying *Rick **reviewed** the paper*), we'd say...

> This paper has already been **pronounced upon** by Sam Rick. *(or **assessed, evaluated**, etc.)*

Answer (score 0):

The "by Sam Rick" part makes every construction sound a little odd, like Sam Rick is speaking about himself in third person (probably not), or Sam Rick's assistant is writing his emails. Either way, I would put the sentence in active voice and say,

> Sam Rick has already reached his decision on this paper.

Comment: I think the problem with your rephrasing is it casts Rick as the "primary" agent (it would be a slightly odd form to use if there were in fact dozens of other people who *could* have decided). OP's looking for a way to express the "state" of the *paper*, not how to say what some (possibly irrelevant) individual might have done.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I think so, but then who is Sam Rick? Why not just say "A decision on this paper has already been reached." Passive with no subject makes the sentence about the state of the paper.

Comment: Well, yes - of course you can "airbrush out" Sam Rick by saying, for example, *"A decision on this paper has already been reached"*. I guess I just meant that since OP's example sentence is of the form *"**This paper has already been** [subjected to some process]"*, we should look for a form of words that keeps as much as possible of his original structure. But there's nothing inherently wrong with your suggestion, obviously - unlike the one I put up as a "theoretical possibility", yours is both "natural phrasing" *and* has the benefit of using a variant of OP's specific word *decision*.

Comment: ...but I don't see anything odd about mentioning Sam Rick in any of these formulations. Perhaps there are hundreds of reviewers, and OP just happens to know the name of the particular one of his "co-workers" who dealt with the paper.